# Label Textbox ServerControl

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

Can I create a server control, where it loads as a label and on user click becomes a text box with two buttons(save,cancel) on the bottom right corner and then on pressing save becomes a label again with the entered text or cancel will cancel the edit(if any) and becomes a label again with the existing text?

Comment: yes you can do it using javascript, like add a click event on the label and in this write the logic to show the textbox and two buttons in it and hide the label and add click event of both buttons and on click of them do whatever you want and in last show the label again and hide these added controls thats it..

Comment: See my answer it may help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a JSfiddle for the same:-

http://jsfiddle.net/c2S5d/29/

Code:-

```
$(function() {
    $("#lbl").click(function() {

        var text = $("#lbl").text();
        $("#lbl").hide();
        $("#edit").show();
        $("#text").val(text);
    });
    $("#save").click(function() {
        //make call to server if you want to save the value in DB
        var text = $("#text").val();
        $("#lbl").text(text);
        $("#edit").hide();
        $("#lbl").show();

    });
    $("#cancel").click(function() {

        $("#edit").hide();
        $("#lbl").show();

    });
});
```

in Save button event you can make ajax call or whatever you want to do...

Answer (score 0):

- You can do this using `visible` property  `visible=true OR visible=false`
- Most `asp` controls have `visible` property - [More information for visible property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.visible(v=vs.100).aspx)